# How to install rabbitmq management plugin (rabbitmq-plugins)

Tags: ubuntu, rabbitmq

Brief:
Is there a way to install rabbitmq-plugins via a ubuntu package?

Details:

I have rabbitmq running ok in my ubuntu system, and now I'm trying to monitor what's going on via the management plugin. I'm following rabbitmq.com/management.html instructions, but can't execute

```
rabbitmq-plugins enable rabbitmq_management
```

because my system does not have rabbitmq-plugins installed.

It's Ubuntu 1110, and came with rabbitmq installed as a package (aptitude install rabbitmq-server librabbitmq-dev). The config and the server are running fine (the installed version is 2.5.0).

Thought that the plugin would get installed by installing "sudo aptitude install rabbitmq-plugins-common", but doing that does not install rabbitmq-plugins.

Is there a package that will install the plugin?  I'd like to avoid if possible having to purge the rabbitmq server that is running ok, and then reinstall it via a download + build from source, all just to get the plugin.

Thanks.

Comment: Beau, thanks for the pointer. I re-posted the question in askubuntu, but will leave it here as well a little longer since it seems to draw a much larger number of rabbitmq community members than ubuntu, and someone may have had the same issue.

Answer (score 37, accepted):

The rabbitmq-plugins script (and the whole concept of bundling plugins with the server release) was only introduced in RabbitMQ 2.7.0. If you want to keep using 2.5.0 then you should download the necessary plugin binaries from http://www.rabbitmq.com/releases/plugins/, drop them in /usr/lib/rabbitmq/lib/rabbitmq_server-2.5.0/plugins/ and restart.

(The necessary binaries for management are amqp_client, mochiweb, webmachine, rabbitmq_mochiweb, rabbitmq_management_agent and rabbitmq_management.)

If that sounds like a pain (well, this is why we changed it in 2.7.0!), you should consider upgrading to 2.7.1. You don't need to build from source - we make .deb packages available and have an apt repository - see http://www.rabbitmq.com/install-debian.html

Comment: I have ubuntu 12.04 and rabbitmq 2.7.1 but no rabbitmq-plugins?!

Comment: @Stefano have a look in the following location /usr/lib/rabbitmq/lib/rabbitmq_server-2.7.1/sbin/ which is where I found the rabbitmq-plugins file

Comment: @AidenMontgomery thanks indeed!! but why isn't that on the /usr/bin path by default?!

Comment: I tried to copy management plugin as per the above...but rabbitmq refuses to start. The other plugins seem to work OK. Strange.

Comment: I want to install v3.7.4 from source. Its building fine but I dont see any plugins there how do I get to start management plugin and access the UI?

Answer (score 71):

If you are using Ubuntu 12.04

Steps are:--

My rabbitmq server version

```
# dpkg -l rabbitmq-server
Desired=Unknown/Install/Remove/Purge/Hold
| Status=Not/Inst/Conf-files/Unpacked/halF-conf/Half-inst/trig-aWait/Trig-pend
|/ Err?=(none)/Reinst-required (Status,Err: uppercase=bad)
||/ Name                Version             Description
+++-===================-===================-======================================================
ii  rabbitmq-server     2.7.1-0ubuntu4      An AMQP server written in Erlang

# apt-get install rabbitmq-server

# /usr/lib/rabbitmq/lib/rabbitmq_server-2.7.1/sbin/rabbitmq-plugins list
[ ] amqp_client                       0.0.0
[ ] eldap                             0.0.0-git
[ ] erlando                           0.0.0
[ ] mochiweb                          1.3-rmq0.0.0-git
[ ] rabbitmq_auth_backend_ldap        0.0.0
[ ] rabbitmq_auth_mechanism_ssl       0.0.0
[ ] rabbitmq_consistent_hash_exchange 0.0.0
[ ] rabbitmq_federation               0.0.0
[ ] rabbitmq_jsonrpc                  0.0.0
[ ] rabbitmq_jsonrpc_channel          0.0.0
[ ] rabbitmq_jsonrpc_channel_examples 0.0.0
[ ] rabbitmq_management               0.0.0
[ ] rabbitmq_management_agent         0.0.0
[ ] rabbitmq_management_visualiser    0.0.0
[ ] rabbitmq_mochiweb                 0.0.0
[ ] rabbitmq_shovel                   0.0.0
[ ] rabbitmq_shovel_management        0.0.0
[ ] rabbitmq_stomp                    0.0.0
[ ] rabbitmq_tracing                  0.0.0
[ ] rfc4627_jsonrpc                   0.0.0-git
[ ] webmachine                        1.7.0-rmq0.0.0-hg
```

Now to enable the web UI plugin

```
# /usr/lib/rabbitmq/lib/rabbitmq_server-2.7.1/sbin/rabbitmq-plugins enable rabbitmq_management
The following plugins have been enabled:
  mochiweb
  webmachine
  rabbitmq_mochiweb
  amqp_client
  rabbitmq_management_agent
  rabbitmq_management
```

Plugin configuration has changed. Restart RabbitMQ for changes to take effect.

```
root@ubuntu:/usr/lib/rabbitmq/lib/rabbitmq_server-2.7.1/sbin# service rabbitmq-server restart
Restarting rabbitmq-server: SUCCESS
rabbitmq-server
```

.

```
root@ubuntu:/usr/lib/rabbitmq/lib/rabbitmq_server-2.7.1/sbin# /usr/lib/rabbitmq/lib/rabbitmq_server-2.7.1/sbin/rabbitmq-plugins list

[e] amqp_client                       0.0.0
[ ] eldap                             0.0.0-git
[ ] erlando                           0.0.0
[e] mochiweb                          1.3-rmq0.0.0-git
[ ] rabbitmq_auth_backend_ldap        0.0.0
[ ] rabbitmq_auth_mechanism_ssl       0.0.0
[ ] rabbitmq_consistent_hash_exchange 0.0.0
[ ] rabbitmq_federation               0.0.0
[ ] rabbitmq_jsonrpc                  0.0.0
[ ] rabbitmq_jsonrpc_channel          0.0.0
[ ] rabbitmq_jsonrpc_channel_examples 0.0.0
[E] rabbitmq_management               0.0.0
[e] rabbitmq_management_agent         0.0.0
[ ] rabbitmq_management_visualiser    0.0.0
[e] rabbitmq_mochiweb                 0.0.0
[ ] rabbitmq_shovel                   0.0.0
[ ] rabbitmq_shovel_management        0.0.0
[ ] rabbitmq_stomp                    0.0.0
[ ] rabbitmq_tracing                  0.0.0
[ ] rfc4627_jsonrpc                   0.0.0-git
[e] webmachine                        1.7.0-rmq0.0.0-hg
```

Check the Web UI

on your browser try `http://localhost:55672` (or `http://localhost:15672` for newer versions of rabbitmq) & login via default user and password which is guest:guest & you will be able to see it all.

Hope it helps.

Comment: [Port 15672 from Rabbitmq version 3.0 onwards](https://www.rabbitmq.com/management.html). The answer worked for version 3.1.5 except the port number (Rabbitmq version check (sudo rabbitmqctl status).

Answer (score 18):

Once you installed erlang and rabbitmq-server you can find rabbitmq-plugin installed in the following directory:

```
/usr/lib/rabbitmq/bin/rabbitmq-plugins
```

then, do a symlink like this,

```
sudo ln -s /usr/lib/rabbitmq/bin/rabbitmq-plugins /usr/local/bin/rabbitmq-plugins
```

after this you are done.

For plugin management, see the below file.

```
sudo vim /etc/rabbitmq/enabled_plugins
```

Answer (score 2):

I exactly faced this problem on Ubuntu 18.04.1 and was not able to enable the rabbitmq_management.

In my case mistake I did was to instal erlang after rabbitmq-server so it was not working fine. (not fully sure why but was getting exact same problem)

As solution I just uninstalled the rabbitmq-server, installed the rabbitmq-server again and all worked just fine below are the complete steps if can help others.

```
sudo apt-get remove rabbitmq-server
sudo apt-get install rabbitmq-server
sudo systemctl enable rabbitmq-server
sudo systemctl start rabbitmq-server
sudo systemctl status rabbitmq-server (to check status only)
sudo rabbitmq-plugins enable rabbitmq_management
sudo rabbitmqctl add_user admin admin
sudo rabbitmqctl set_user_tags admin administrator
```

Answer (score 0):

rabbitmq-plugins enable rabbitmq_management,
this command is for recent versions of rabbitmq, rabbitmq_management is included in rabbitmq 2.8.5, it actually activates 6 plugins, which in older versions are downloads to RABBITMQ_PLUGINS_DIR, which set in script rabbitmq-server.
so it is easier to upgrade your rabbitmq.

here are 6 plugins :
    Activating RabbitMQ plugins ...
    6 plugins activated:

- amqp_client-0.0.0
- mochiweb-2.3.1-rmq0.0.0-gitd541e9a
- rabbitmq_management-0.0.0
- rabbitmq_management_agent-0.0.0
- rabbitmq_mochiweb-0.0.0
- webmachine-1.9.1-rmq0.0.0-git52e62bc

Comment: I want to install v3.7.4 from source. Its building fine but I dont see any plugins there how do I get to start management plugin and access the UI?

Answer (score -1):

I also faced the same problem while installing the rabbitmq in ubuntu os.

I have written a tutorial for this [how to install rabbitmq in ubuntu](https://codesquery.com/install-and-manage-rabbitmq-in-ubuntu/). If you are still facing the issue then you can refer that tutorial. Hope this will help you.