# RabbitMQ: handshake error when attempting to use SSL certificates

Tags: ssl, rabbitmq

I am trying to use SSL certificates with RabbitMQ but I keep getting handshake errors with the broker.

The certificates that I have generated work fine when using the openssl 's_client' and 's_server' commands in separate terminal windows and utilizing port 8443 as detailed in the SSL Troubleshooting guide (http://www.rabbitmq.com/troubleshooting-ssl.html).

The problem appears when I attempt to connect to the RabbitMQ SSL port 5671 using the same openssl 's_client' command:

Running this:

```
openssl s_client -connect localhost:5671 -cert /etc/rabbitmq/ssl/client/cert.pem -key /etc/rabbitmq/ssl/client/key.pem -CAfile /etc/rabbitmq/ssl/certificate_auth/cacert.pem
```

Produces this:

```
CONNECTED(00000003)
depth=1 CN = RMQCA
verify return:1
depth=0 CN = roger.xxxxxx.com, O = server
verify return:1
139997248210760:error:14094410:SSL routines:SSL3_READ_BYTES:sslv3 alert handshake failure:s3_pkt.c:1256:SSL alert number 40
139997248210760:error:140790E5:SSL routines:SSL23_WRITE:ssl handshake  failure:s23_lib.c:177:
---
```

The SSL listener starts fine as indicated in the RabbitMQ log:

```
=INFO REPORT==== 19-May-2014::15:45:34 ===
 started TCP Listener on [::]:5672

=INFO REPORT==== 19-May-2014::15:45:34 ===
 started SSL Listener on [::]:5671
```

When attempting to connect to port 5671 with 's_client' the error appears:

```
=INFO REPORT==== 19-May-2014::17:20:39 ===
accepting AMQP connection <0.3263.0> ([::1]:58538 -> [::1]:5671)

=ERROR REPORT==== 19-May-2014::17:20:39 ===
SSL: certify: ssl_handshake.erl:1346:Fatal error: handshake failure

=ERROR REPORT==== 19-May-2014::17:20:44 ===
error on AMQP connection <0.3263.0>: {ssl_upgrade_error,
                                      {tls_alert,"handshake failure"}} (unknown POSIX error)
```

RabbitMQ Config file:

```
[    
    {rabbit, [
      {ssl_listeners, [5671]},
      {ssl_options, [{cacertfile, "/etc/rabbitmq/ssl/certificate_auth/cacert.pem"},
                     {certfile, "/etc/rabbitmq/ssl/server/cert.pem"},
                     {keyfile, "/etc/rabbitmq/ssl/server/key.pem"},
                     {verify, verify_peer},
                     {fail_if_no_peer_cert, false}]}
     ]} 
].
```

RabbitMQ info:

```
[{pid,10375},
 {running_applications,
     [{rabbitmq_management,"RabbitMQ Management Console","3.2.3"},
      {rabbitmq_web_dispatch,"RabbitMQ Web Dispatcher","3.2.3"},
      {webmachine,"webmachine","1.10.3-rmq3.2.3-gite9359c7"},
      {mochiweb,"MochiMedia Web Server","2.7.0-rmq3.2.3-git680dba8"},
      {rabbitmq_management_agent,"RabbitMQ Management Agent","3.2.3"},
      {rabbit,"RabbitMQ","3.2.3"},
      {ssl,"Erlang/OTP SSL application","5.3.3"},
      {public_key,"Public key infrastructure","0.21"},
      {crypto,"CRYPTO version 2","3.2"},
      {asn1,"The Erlang ASN1 compiler version 2.0.4","2.0.4"},
      {os_mon,"CPO  CXC 138 46","2.2.14"},
      {inets,"INETS  CXC 138 49","5.9.8"},
      {mnesia,"MNESIA  CXC 138 12","4.11"},
      {amqp_client,"RabbitMQ AMQP Client","3.2.3"},
      {xmerl,"XML parser","1.3.6"},
      {sasl,"SASL  CXC 138 11","2.3.4"},
      {stdlib,"ERTS  CXC 138 10","1.19.4"},
      {kernel,"ERTS  CXC 138 10","2.16.4"}]},
 {os,{unix,linux}},
 {erlang_version,
     "Erlang R16B03-1 (erts-5.10.4) [source] [64-bit] [smp:2:2] [async-threads:30] [hipe] [kernel-poll:true]\n"},
 {memory,
     [{total,43812088},
      {connection_procs,5616},
      {queue_procs,42528},
      {plugins,451248},
      {other_proc,13805200},
      {mnesia,72752},
      {mgmt_db,10208},
      {msg_index,34560},
      {other_ets,1159472},
      {binary,1030272},
      {code,21819091},
      {atom,793505},
      {other_system,4587636}]},
 {vm_memory_high_watermark,0.4},
 {vm_memory_limit,787819724},
 {disk_free_limit,50000000},
 {disk_free,31267266560},
 {file_descriptors,
     [{total_limit,924},{total_used,4},{sockets_limit,829},{sockets_used,2}]},
 {processes,[{limit,1048576},{used,215}]},
 {run_queue,0},
 {uptime,7893}]
...done.
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated

Thanks in advance.

UPDATE:

I get the following errors when trying to connect with the rabbitmqadmin utility.

Log File:

```
=INFO REPORT==== 20-May-2014::14:39:12 ===
accepting AMQP connection <0.16589.0> ([::1]:58922 -> [::1]:5671)

=ERROR REPORT==== 20-May-2014::14:39:12 ===
SSL: certify: ssl_handshake.erl:1346:Fatal error: handshake failure

=ERROR REPORT==== 20-May-2014::14:39:17 ===
error on AMQP connection <0.16589.0>: {ssl_upgrade_error,
                                       {tls_alert,"handshake failure"}} (unknown POSIX error)
```

The rabbitmqadmin command produced the following:

```
*** Could not connect: [Errno 1] _ssl.c:492: error:14094410:SSL routines:SSL3_READ_BYTES:sslv3 alert handshake failure
```

Comment: Do you experience this issue with openssl cli utility only? Have you tried [rabbitmqadmin](http://www.rabbitmq.com/management-cli.html) utility?

Comment: Did you ever resolve your issue?

Answer (score 11):

I had the same problem as @user3653959 and @Sarah Messer's answer lead me to the solution.

Your **client certificate must have** the `TLS Web Client Authentication` "X509v3 Extended Key Usage" attribute. Mine had only `TLS Web Server Authentication` due to an error in my client generation script.

To check your client certificate's capabilities, you can use the this command:

```
openssl x509 -noout -text -in client-certificate.pem
```

Then look for the "*X509v3 extensions:*" section and the "*X509v3 Extended Key Usage:*" subsection.

If you generate your client certificate using the example `openssl.conf` and client and server commands provided in the official ["RabbitMQ - TLS Support" guide](https://www.rabbitmq.com/ssl.html#keys-and-certs), it should work out of the box.

The key here is the `extendedKeyUsage = 1.3.6.1.5.5.7.3.2` openssl config option in `openssl.conf` as @Sarah Messer points out. This is the "TLS Web Client Authentication" capability. OpenSSL `s_server` does not require this capability and that's why it works by default with it, but not with RabbitMQ. `keyUsage = digitalSignature` is enough as main usage options. Also, the "Common Name" (`CN`) of the client certificate is not important.

#### Just for reference

My environment:

- RabbitMQ 3.6.2
- Erlang 18.2
- Ubuntu 14.04.2 LTS (64-bit)
- Only TLSv1.2 enabled.

The error I was seeing in my RabbitMQ log:

```
=ERROR REPORT==== 21-Jun-2016::13:28:21 ===
SSL: certify: ssl_handshake.erl:1492:Fatal error: handshake failure
```

The error I was seeing via `openssl s_client`:

```
140735165813584:error:14094410:SSL routines:ssl3_read_bytes:sslv3 alert handshake failure:s3_pkt.c:1472:SSL alert number 40
140735165813584:error:1409E0E5:SSL routines:ssl3_write_bytes:ssl handshake failure:s3_pkt.c:656:
```

Comment: My issue was very close to this and this helped me resolve it, while I had the correct `extendedKeyUsage` I was actually signing my client certificate as a server certificate. Pay attention that your openssl command is executing the right extensions name. (It is the `-extensions XXXX` flag)

Answer (score 4):

I worked my way through similar troubles (using RabbitMQ 2.7.1 / Erlang R14B04). Here's what I've found:

The RabbitMQ [plugins page](https://www.rabbitmq.com/plugins.html) and at least [one other site](http://weblogs.asp.net/jeffreyabecker/Using-SSL-client-certificates-for-authentication-with-RabbitMQ) recommend enabling the plugin [rabbitmq_auth_mechanism_ssl](http://hg.rabbitmq.com/rabbitmq-auth-mechanism-ssl/file/rabbitmq_v3_3_5/README). If `rabbitmq-plugins` is an invalid command on your system, [this page](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8548983/how-to-install-rabbitmq-management-plugin-rabbitmq-plugins) describes how to enable it on Ubuntu. (Apparently the apt-get package doesn't have quite the expected behavior on Debian-based systems.) Your output (from `rabbitmqctl report`, I presume) says you don't have `rabbitmq_auth_mechanism_ssl` enabled.

For your rabbitmq.config, you'll need to make sure "EXTERNAL" is listed as one of the auth_mechanisms. The line's syntax is `{auth_mechanisms, ['PLAIN', 'AMQPLAIN', 'EXTERNAL']}` and appears as one item in the default, "rabbit" portion of the configuration.

You should also make sure the certificate your client presents has the appropriate values set for both `keyUsage` and `extendedKeyUsage`, as RabbitMQ is more strict about these than s_server. For debugging / testing purposes, you may want to be extremely permissive with these. You can set the keyUsage in your [openssl config](https://www.openssl.org/docs/apps/x509v3_config.html). A broadly-acceptable openssl config may have lines like this

`keyUsage = digitalSignature, nonRepudiation, keyEncipherment, dataEncipherment, keyAgreement, keyCertSign, cRLSign
extendedKeyUsage = 1.3.6.1.5.5.7.3.1, 1.3.6.1.5.5.7.3.2`

(I think the .2 OID, "TLS Web Client Authentication" is important for connecting to RabbitMQ, but I haven't done careful tests.)

This will produce certificates with this block near the end:

`X509v3 Key Usage: 
                Digital Signature, Non Repudiation, Key Encipherment, Data Encipherment, Key Agreement, Certificate Sign, CRL Sign
            X509v3 Extended Key Usage: 
                TLS Web Server Authentication, TLS Web Client Authentication`

There should be more output from s_client. In particular, I'm interested in the final line, which should look something like "Verify return code: 0 (ok)" If you have a non-zero / error message there, post it and pivot off that in your searches. (#19 is surprisingly common, given that it's [not really an error](http://www.microfocus.co.jp/manuals/ED21/html/HHSTSTCERT06.html).)

When I got to this point, when I tried to make a simple `pika.BlockingConnection`, the handshake apparently completed just fine, but Rabbit removed EXTERNAL from the list specified in `auth_mechanisms` in the config. I confirmed I had rabbitmq_auth_mechanism_ssl enabled, but that by itself wasn't enough. (I discovered this by subclassing `pika.credentials.ExternalCredentials` and pass an instance as the "credentials" item in ConnectionParameters, adding a `print start` at the top of the subclass's `response_for()` method.) I fixed that by adding the following line to the `rabbit` portion of the config file, on the same level as `ssl_listeners` and `ssl_cert_login_from`:

`{ssl_apps,[asn1,crypto,public_key,ssl]},`

(I suspect newer versions of RabbitMQ turn that on by default, but my particular setup did not.)

If you've done all that and you're still having trouble, you might also try replacing "verify_peer" with "verify_none" in your RabbitMQ config. You probably don't want that in production, since it opens you up to anyone with a self-signed certificate, but it's another data point. Also, subclass the relevant things in pika and add in print statements to get more insight on what Rabbit's sending you and how your local client's interpreting it.

Comment: Getting same error "SSL: certify: ssl_connection.erl:826:Fatal error: handshake failure", for .net even if openssl s_client successfully connect with same set of certs. My client cert has "TLS Web Client Authentication" in extended key usage section

Answer (score -1):

Here is the solution which worked for me:

Adding below ciphers in rabbitmq.config:

```
{ciphers, ["ECDHE-ECDSA-AES256-GCM-SHA384","ECDHE-RSA-AES256-GCM-SHA384",
                        "ECDHE-ECDSA-AES256-SHA384","ECDHE-RSA-AES256-SHA384", "ECDHE-ECDSA-DES-CBC3-SHA",
                        "ECDH-ECDSA-AES256-GCM-SHA384","ECDH-RSA-AES256-GCM-SHA384","ECDH-ECDSA-AES256-SHA384",
                        "ECDH-RSA-AES256-SHA384","DHE-DSS-AES256-GCM-SHA384","DHE-DSS-AES256-SHA256",
                        "AES256-GCM-SHA384","AES256-SHA256","ECDHE-ECDSA-AES128-GCM-SHA256",
                        "ECDHE-RSA-AES128-GCM-SHA256","ECDHE-ECDSA-AES128-SHA256","ECDHE-RSA-AES128-SHA256",
                        "ECDH-ECDSA-AES128-GCM-SHA256","ECDH-RSA-AES128-GCM-SHA256","ECDH-ECDSA-AES128-SHA256",
                        "ECDH-RSA-AES128-SHA256","DHE-DSS-AES128-GCM-SHA256","DHE-DSS-AES128-SHA256",
                        "AES128-GCM-SHA256","AES128-SHA256","ECDHE-ECDSA-AES256-SHA",
                        "ECDHE-RSA-AES256-SHA","DHE-DSS-AES256-SHA","ECDH-ECDSA-AES256-SHA",
                        "ECDH-RSA-AES256-SHA","AES256-SHA","ECDHE-ECDSA-AES128-SHA",
                        "ECDHE-RSA-AES128-SHA","DHE-DSS-AES128-SHA","ECDH-ECDSA-AES128-SHA",
                        "ECDH-RSA-AES128-SHA","AES128-SHA"]},
                  {fail_if_no_peer_cert,false}]}
    ]}
]
```